# Haskell basic [Either a b] input argument

Tags: haskell

How do i write the input argument for the following function guys??

A word is a list of such symbols, it has type [Either sigma var].
So, my second input will be a word and I don't know where to start about it.
I think I can't write [Left sigma] or [Right var] since the whole either is type of a word..
Please help me out or please point me to somewhere i can read about it :)

```
genstep :: CFG sigma var -> [Either sigma var] -> [[Either sigma var]]
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of `CFG`?

Comment: data CFG sigma var = CFG { start :: var,prod :: var -> [[Either sigma var]]}

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to start you off. Given a particular value of type `CFG sigma var`, the second argument can only be one of three things - either it's empty, or the first element is a `Left`, or the first element is a `Right`.

That means your function definition can start with

```
genstep :: CFG sigma var -> [Either sigma var] -> [[Either sigma var]]
genstep cfg []             = -- your definition here
genstep cfg (Left  s:rest) = -- your definition here
genstep cfg (Right v:rest) = -- your definition here
```

Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: appreciate it mate :) 
now, i will try to do it :)